# Observing Task exceptions within a ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

There are various ways in which to observe exceptions thrown within tasks.  One of them is in a ContinueWith with OnlyOnFaulted:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Throws an exception 
    // (possibly from within another task spawned from within this task)
});

var failureTask = task.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    // Flatten and loop (since there could have been multiple tasks)
    foreach (var ex in t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

My question:  Do the exceptions become automatically observed once failureTask begins or do they only become observed once I 'touch' ex.Message?

Comment: What do you mean by observed?  Your ContinueWith delegate will only be called once, if that's what you mean, regardless of whether you access the exception object or not.

Comment: Perhaps he means "will it rethrow the exception if I simply call `OnlyOnFaulted` regardless of accessing `t.Exceptions`"?

Comment: If you do not "observe" exceptions (this is Microsoft terminology) thrown from Tasks, then the garbage collector will throw them for you at a later point.  My ContinueWith delegate surely could get called multiple times (if multiple tasks from within my main task throw exceptions)... or it could get called with an AggregateException tree with all thrown exceptions?

Comment: "Just scheduling a continuation off of t1 is not sufficient to observe its exception... you need to actually look at the exception in some way, either by Wait'ing on it so that the exception is thrown, or accessing its Exception property after the task has faulted, etc.".  Ok, so I actually need to look at the Exception to observe it.  Source:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/dbe2ccae-3f9c-458d-b89f-ca580ddc3a50/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are viewed as *observed* once you access the `Exception` property.

See also `AggregateException.Handle`.  You can use `t.Exception.Handle` instead:

```
t.Exception.Handle(exception =>
            {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
            return true;
            }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that there are many ways in which to handle task exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda prefer the Handle method; because it's more explicit.  But, it might not be usable in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

sample

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(testMethod).ContinueWith(p =>
            {
                if (p.Exception != null)
                    p.Exception.Handle(x =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
                            return false;
                        });
            });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the predicate passed to the Handle() function here return true if you want to mark the exceptions as handled (like the previous answer above)? I suppose it depends what you want to do, but I'm presuming here we want to mark the exception as handled.